# Center scores for the SVS57 survey

Tags: stata

I am using the Schwartz Values Survey (SVS57) to determine personal values of my respondents. The survey guide states that the scores need to be adjusted for the scale use differences among respondents in order to get valid scale scores. The guide states the following:

> A. Compute each individual’s total score on all value items and divide by the total number of items (56 or 57). I call this the MRAT (Mean RATing for the particular individual).
>
> B. Center scores of each of the items for an individual on that    individual’s MRAT.

I computed the MRAT scores in Stata by `egen MRAT = rowmean(pvalues*)`. I now need to center the items of every respondent around that respondent's MRAT score (part B) and I'm stuck here.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what code to use or maybe in what direction to search? I only found information on standardising towards z-scores with a mean of 0 and SD of 1, not what needs to happen here. Is centering in this case nothing more then subtracting the mean or is there something more to it?

Comment: Given your comments below, this question would be better placed in [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). If it doesn't get traction there, you might try reading through the methodology section of the survey documentation, and finally emailing those who maintain the survey.

Answer (score 0):

How best to handle data like this, including the arcana of survey items, is in my view off-topic here. But your programming question appears to be how to subtract the mean, which you have already put into a variable, from a bundle of variables. So you want a loop

```
foreach v of var pvalues* { 
    gen `v'_c = `v' - MRAT 
}
```

This qualifies as rather elementary on a forum intended for professional and enthusiast programmers. In any language, finding about loops is basic. In Stata `search foreach` for some resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick. My question in this case was not so much how to do a loop but more whether the standard procedure of subtracting the mean is the appropriate manner in this case since the SVS57 survey is a widely used statistical surveying method and maybe others have experience with the data manipulations needed for this. As I am typing this I realise that It is probably off-topic for the Stata area of SO and more a research specific question. my apologies for this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. I just got hold of someone that has more experience with the SVS57 survey and it is indeed nothing more then the standard centering by subtracting the mean score. I used a foreach loop that is similar to the one suggested by Nick.

```
egen P_MRAT = rowmean(pvalues1-pvalues20)

foreach var of varlist pvalues1-pvalues20 {
generate c_`var' = `var' – P_MRAT
}
```